# OnAuthorization causes Redirect Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, authorization

I have added a request to change password in my application. To make sure that user is redirected to a view where User can update a password, I have created a custom `ExtendedAuthorize` attribute and overridden its `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)`. Then I decorated each controller with this attribute. The attribute simply checks if User has to change a password and eventually redirects to the corresponding view if that's the case. This however causes Redirect Loop. I am afraid it is because the application redirects to `UpdatePassword` action which is also decorated with this attribute and consequently it makes a browser to come back to `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)` method of `ExtendedAuthorize` etc. and this is repeated infinitly.

I don't know how to sort it. I tried to put default attribute [Authorize] but it does not help. I also tried to change it to [AllowAnonymous] but it's still causing Redirect Loop. Any advice on how I can prevent an action from executing a controller attribute is very appreciated.

Perhaps it is possible to put two different attributes such as [CustomAuthorize1, CustomAuthorize2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve this problem would be to check in your `ExtendedAuthorize` attribute whether the `OnAuthorization` is running at the page you want the user to redirect to.

I guess your `ExtendedAuthorize` is something like the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _redirectActionName;
    private readonly string _redirectControllerName;

    SimpleAuthorizeAttribute(string redirectActionName, string redirectControllerName)
    {
        _redirectActionName = redirectActionName;
        _redirectControllerName = redirectControllerName;
    }

    public string RedirectActionName 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _redirectActionName;
        } 
    }

    public string RedirectControllerName 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _redirectControllerName;
        } 
    }
}
```

In this case you just need to check whether the OnAuthorize is running on the page you want the user to redirect to:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

    if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == RedirectActionName && 
       filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == RedirectControllerName)
    {
        return;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tested and the `OnAuthorization` indeed run on the redirected page. I did not know how to do the condition test. Cheers!